# jupyterlab not initalize from Anaconda Naviagtor

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have problems with jupyterlab, this bug consist in want initialize from Anaconda Navigator appear this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-script.py", in line 10, in sys.exit(main())
```

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 247, in main command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand) File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 134, in _jupyter_abspath 'Jupyter command `{}` not found.'.format(jupyter_subcommand) Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-lab` not found.

but when search the archive jupyter-lab.exe and executed the jupyterlab this work with normally; until today occurred this problem, and my questions are why occurred? and how can solved?

Comment: open normal cmd  and execute this command  >>>    jupyter-lab

Comment: Wow, be initialize jupyterlab, but intrigue me this message in cmd: [W 20:53:24.206 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs

Comment: open cmd >>execute>>pip install jupyterlab>>>after installation>>execute thiscommand>>jupyter-lab

Comment: Be initialize again, but this message persist: [W 14:45:20.023 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs

Comment: on the basis of my knowledge jupyter lab require node js only when you want add more configuration setting.if on downloading node.js it may resolve problem then download nodejs from offical website

Comment: Ok thanks for your support, and i try download node.js but it's strange the jupyterlab work with normally until a few days ago

Comment: Not, the problem persists